# Android ebooks in Html or EPUB

Tags: java, android, html, xamarin, epub

I'm building an Android app which will allow the user to read some content, navigate, and to search through it.
I'm not sure whether the right format for this is Html, and put it in a WebView, or whether I should use EPUB for the files?
Which is better for this kind of usage, what are the pros and cons of each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If application is just for your content. I think it's not really important. It can be anything. If reading is the main idea of application I would use epub with [epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android).

If it's book reader I think http is not a option at all. Most books you can find in epub and other formats.
Most popular book [formats](http://www.edudemic.com/most-popular-ebook-formats-2/).

If your application it's mobile version of blog or something like that. Then maybe is better to use a html. 
So it depends what exactly your app about.